# Conditional execution by checking pixel color in AutoHotkey Coding,

Tags: autohotkey

I want this sub script to check the pixel color of specific coordinates, `X1013 Y-381`. If this color is `e048c5` then have it press the "Esc" button. How could you do this?

Comment: Hi Worth The Ban, welcome to Stack Overflow, please provide some code to get help. Also you can take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know how to ask a question ;)

Comment: The coordinates are relative to what?

Answer (score 0):

```js
PixelGetColor, color, 1013, -381, RGB
if (color = 0xe048c5) 
  Send {Esc}
```